# jssor thumbnail scrolling with different thumbnail width

Tags: jssor, scroller

I would like to use the jssor Thumbnail (logo) scroller with images (thumbnails) of different size.
I cannot found where I can modify the settings.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Every slide in jssor slider is in fixed size. What you can do is to specify $FillMode option to fit your image in each slide.

```
var options = {
    ...
    $FillMode: 0,
    ...
};
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html

Comment: Thank you can you send me an example, I do not understand correctly how to use "$FillMode option to fit your image in each slide"

Comment: OK Thanks, this mean that the DIV slide will always be the same size and my content will just stay at the same ratio...

Comment: There is no way to keep my image thinner between 2 DIV with the content.
Please confirm.

Comment: If you set $FillMode to 4, your image will keep actual size. And you can try other fill mode.

Comment: You know, each slide is in fixed size, you can only place your image in each slide. So, you can never see any slide thinner.